# How to use web authentication api on multiple devices and if user is pre-created by system

Tags: webauthn

Can please advise on what to do on the following scenarios if I were to use Web authentication API for authenticating to my website?

1. My website has an admin page that only admin users can access.  Before deploying my website, I need to create credentials for admin users so they can use this when logging in. This means they don't need to register to my website. Cause traditionally, when we create admin users, we configure the username and password that they can use.  In this case, what will be the flow to enable web authentication?
2. What if the device (Phone or laptop) has no biometrics?  Do I enable password input if there's no biometrics but biometrics signup/login will be the default?
3. My website is both accessible from phone and laptop.  If the user signs up using the phone therefore sending the public key to the server, what will happen if the user tries to login from laptop next time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You cannot pre-register public keys for admin users, since there's no way for you to provide the corresponding private key to be loaded into user's authenticator. What you can do is create the user accounts with a unique link and one-time password, that the user can use to complete registration with Webauthn (the private key will be generated on the authenticator).
2. Biometrics is just one way of doing local user verification. It depends on the authenticator, but a few examples are a PIN (eg USB-based authenticators) or a swipe pattern (Android).
3. There are a few ways for this:

   - Passkeys can be synced via the cloud, useful for when both devices belong to the same ecosystem (eg Apple iCloud).
   - The desktop browser can show a QR code for the phone to scan and then set up a connection with the desktop, this works well across ecosystems. This is called the 'hybrid' transport.

For the last two points, see https://passkeys.dev/ for more info or this demo: https://www.w3.org/2022/09/TPAC/demos/passkeys.html